# Find and delete list of file names within subfolders on my web server

Tags: linux, server, command, cpanel

I have a list of about 200 image file names. On the web server there are multiple instances of files with these file names within a subfolder structure within one directory.

Is there a command I can run to find all instances of these file names and delete them?

example of file names

- image-488363450-1.jpg
- somename-186758341-1.jpg
- randomname-588968004-1.jpg
- blabla124405236-1-1.jpg
- someimage_MEDIUM.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file "badFiles" file holds a list of filenames that you would like to delete, and "myDirs" holds a list of subdirectories in which they could be, the following should work:

```
for file in `cat badFiles`
do
  for dir in `cat myDirs`
  do
    [ -f ${dir}/${file} ] && rm ${dir}/${file}
  done
done
```

If the list of directories includes all subdirectories from your current working directory, then the following should work without creating the myDirs file:

```
for file in `cat badFiles`
do
  for dir in *
  do
    [ -d ${dir} ] && [ -f ${dir}/${file} ] && rm ${dir}/${file}
  done
done
```

To call this over SSH, you can put the contents of the below script into a file (in this example, I will use the location ${HOME}/bin/killImages.sh):

Edit ~/bin/killImages.sh, and use the contents below.  Once complete, write and save.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
for file in `cat ~/badFiles`
do
  for dir in *
  do
    [ -d ${dir} ] && [ -f ${dir}/${file} ] && rm ${dir}/${file}
  done
done
```

Then make your script executable:

```
chmod 700 ~/bin/killImages.sh
```

Then on your local system, execute:

```
ssh <user>@<hostname> "bin/killImages.sh /path/to/base/html"
```

If you need to manually upload the list of bad files first, you would simply scp this into place before kicking off the script:

```
scp badFiles <user>@<hostname>:.
ssh <user>@<hostname> "bin/killImages.sh /path/to/base/html"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what type of file is badFiles. Is it a .txt file one per line of something else? @paul-h

Comment: If all files match the pattern "image*" or "image*jpg", then I'd go with Lucian's suggestion of leveraging find.  Yes, this will traverse all subdirectories.  If that isn't what you want (you only want one level deeper than the starting directory) this can be controlled with the -depth flag.

Comment: In the above example, badFiles is a plain text file.  In Unix-like operating systems files often are not identified by extensions, and as such text files may not end with "txt".  If you'd like it that way, just create it as such and specify it that way.  You can simply create your list by tossing filenames into badFiles.txt:
     echo "image-488363450-1.jpg" >>badFiles.txt;
etc, etc.  This is a lot of manual labor, though, if your scenario allows you to simply pattern match, and use a find with --exec rm {} \; as noted above.

Comment: yeah no pattern. They are just random file names.

Comment: im doing some testing over ssh. i'm in the working directory with a list of files in a text file. I am confused as to how your commands? @paul-h

Comment: how to use this over ssh?

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation of how to do this over ssh.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name "image*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

- name "FILE-TO-FIND" : File pattern.
- exec rm -rf {} \; : Delete all files matched by file pattern.
- type f : Only match files and do not include directory names.

(this is actually from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/))

Comment: Will this look through subfolders?

Comment: Yes, it looks in subfolders too

Comment: wont work for me as I don't have a pattern to match. its just a list of files

Comment: *a list of files with names that follow no pattern

Comment: If they are all jpg then you can use that as a pattern. If you don't have a pattern then how do you know what to delete? How do you do that manually?